# Tensorflow placeholder in Keras custom objective function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I need to implement a custom objective function for Keras where i need an additional tensorflow placeholder for computation. In tensorflow, i have it as following,

```
pre_cost1 = tf.multiply((self.input_R - self.Decoder) , self.input_mask_R)
cost1 = tf.square(self.l2_norm(pre_cost1))
```

where input_mask_R is the tensorflow placeholder. input_R and Decoder are the placeholders corresponding to y_true and y_pred for Keras loss function respectively. I have the Keras loss function implemented as,

```
def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):

    pre_cost1 = tf.multiply((y_true - y_pred))
    cost1 = tf.square(l2_norm(pre_cost1))

    return cost1
```

I need to add the additional information for input mask in the loss function for keras. (It needs to be tensorflow placeholder since its a mask for the input which is different for each row of the input data).

Comment: Does input_mask_R change during training ? or is it predefined for each input sample ?

Comment: its predefined for each sample

Comment: Could you post the model ? at least a basic one that you are testing with ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the keras backend:

```
import keras.backend as K
```

Most functions for tensors are there, such as:

```
input_mask_R = K.placeholder(shape=(yourshape))
```

But maybe, since you want a predefined mask, what you need is:

```
input_mask_R = K.constant(arrayWithValues, shape=(yourshape))
```

And you can actually multiply and square also with `K.multiply` and `K.square`. That way, if you ever think of changing the backend, everything will be ok. (Also I'm not sure if Keras will handle direct calls to tensorflow functions.....)

See documentation: https://keras.io/backend/

Comment: Yeah from my tests keras handle `tf.square` as a replacement for `K.square`